# Which geopandas datasets (maps) are available?

Tags: maps, geopandas

I just created a very simple geopandas example (see below). It works, but I noticed that it is important for me to be able to have a custom part of the world. Sometimes Germany and sometimes only Berlin. (Also, I want to aggregate the data I have by areas which I define as polygons in a geopandas file, but I'll add this in another question.)

How can I get a different "base map" than

```
world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
```

for visualizations?

### Example

```
# 3rd party modules
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import shapely
# needs 'descartes'

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'city': ['Berlin', 'Paris', 'Munich'],
                   'latitude': [52.518611111111, 48.856666666667, 48.137222222222],
                   'longitude': [13.408333333333, 2.3516666666667, 11.575555555556]})
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df.drop(['latitude', 'longitude'], axis=1),
                       crs={'init': 'epsg:4326'},
                       geometry=[shapely.geometry.Point(xy)
                                 for xy in zip(df.longitude, df.latitude)])
print(gdf)

world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
base = world.plot(color='white', edgecolor='black')
gdf.plot(ax=base, marker='o', color='red', markersize=5)

plt.show()
```

Comment: How can I zoom the `naturalearth_lowres` map into South Africa?

Answer (score 30):

As written in the [`geopandas.datasets.get_path(...)` documentation](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.datasets.get_path.html), one has to execute

```
>>> geopandas.datasets.available
['naturalearth_lowres', 'naturalearth_cities', 'nybb']
```

Where

- naturalearth_lowres: contours of countries
- naturalearth_cities: positions of cities
- nybb: maybe New York?

### Other data sources

Searching for "germany shapefile" gave [an arcgis.com url](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=ae25571c60d94ce5b7fcbf74e27c00e0) which used the "Bundesamt für Kartographie und Geodäsie" as a source. The result of using `vg2500_geo84/vg2500_krs.shp` looks like this:

[image]

Source:

> © Bundesamt für Kartographie und Geodäsie, Frankfurt am Main, 2011
> Vervielfältigung, Verbreitung und öffentliche Zugänglichmachung, auch auszugsweise, mit Quellenangabe gestattet.

I also had to set `base.set_aspect(1.4)`, otherwise it looked wrong. The value `1.4` was found by trial and error.

Another source for such data for Berlin is [daten.berlin.de](https://daten.berlin.de/datensaetze/openstreetmap-daten-f%C3%BCr-berlin)

When geopandas reads the shapefile, it is a geopandas dataframe with the columns

```
['USE', 'RS', 'RS_ALT', 'GEN', 'SHAPE_LENG', 'SHAPE_AREA', 'geometry']
```

with:

- `USE=4` for all elements
- `RS` is a string like 16077 or 01003
- `RS_ALT` is a string like 160770000000 or 010030000000
- `GEN` is a string like `'Saale-Holzland-Kreis'` or `'Erlangen'`
- `SHAPE_LENG` is a float like `202986.1998816` or `248309.91235015`
- `SHAPE_AREA` is a float like `1.91013141e+08` or `1.47727769e+09`
- `geometry` is a shapely geometry - mostly POLYGON

Comment: Maybe https://towardsdatascience.com/lets-make-a-map-using-geopandas-pandas-and-matplotlib-to-make-a-chloropleth-map-dddc31c1983d helps

Comment: nybb is for 'borough boundaries of New York City' : https://data.cityofnewyork.us/City-Government/Borough-Boundaries/tqmj-j8zm